# Isotope unable to hide an element properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

When I "hide" the element by the isotope method, The other element won't slide to left.

I use the latest Isotope.

I initiate my Isotope like that:

```
$container = $('.dt-sc-portfolio-container');
if( $container.length) {
    $width = $container.hasClass("no-space") ? 0 : 20;
    $container.isotope({
        filter: '*',
        masonry: { gutterWidth: $width },
        animationOptions: { duration: 750, easing: 'linear', queue: false  }
    });
}//Isotope End
```

The setup display is like:
[image: original display]

I want to hide an element when I click on view more. I saw on [this like](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#hideitemelements) how to.

```
$container.isotope('hideItemElements', $item.parents('.column'));
```

When I do that I got that:

[image]

I'm looking to slide all other to the left side.

Comment: Is jquery/isotope hiding the element by setting it to `visibility: hidden`? If so, it will continue to occupy space and the other elements will not slide over...

Comment: For one thing, the current version of Isotope has no option "gutterWidth", it's gutter, and no option "animationOptions". A link with all your code or a jsfiddle would be helpful.